# restrict admin panel sections to users

Tags: wp-admin, users, admin-menu, user-access

I have found out how to disable wordpress admin menu items from users other than administratos. What I would like to achieve now is every user can access only his user page (only "Your profile") and edit only some of the details, for example I don't want the user to change his email but he can change his nickname etc.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following, to `functions.php` of the current theme (child theme is preferred!):

**CSS solution:**

```
function no_email_changes_in_profile() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ('profile' == $screen->base && !current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        echo '<style>
input#email {
    pointer-events: none;
}
</style>';
    }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'no_email_changes_in_profile');
```

**jQuery solution:**

```
function no_email_changes_in_profile() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ('profile' == $screen->base && !current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        echo "<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#email').prop('readonly', true);
});
</script>";
    }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'no_email_changes_in_profile');
```

This will disable editing of 'Email' field on the profile admin page, for all users, except of an administrator.